# Splitting a raidctl mirror safely

Tags: raid, solaris, mirror, lsi

I have a Sun T5220 server with the onboard LSI card and two disks that were in a RAID 1 mirror.  The data is not important right now but we had a failed disk and are trying to understand how to do this for real if we had to recover from a failure.

The initial situation looked like this:

```
# raidctl -l c1t0d0
Volume                  Size    Stripe  Status   Cache  RAID
         Sub                     Size                    Level
                 Disk
----------------------------------------------------------------
c1t0d0                  136.6G  N/A     DEGRADED OFF    RAID1
                 0.1.0   136.6G          GOOD
                 N/A     136.6G          FAILED
```

Green light on the 0.0.0 disk.  Find / lights up the 0.1.0 disk.  So I know I have a bad drive and which one it is.  Server still boots obviously.

First, we tried putting a new disk in.  This disk came from an unknown source.  Format would not see it, cfgadm -al would not see it so raidctl -l would not see it.  I figure it's bad.  We tried another disk from another spare server:

```
# raidctl -c c1t1d0 c1t0d0  (where t1 is my good disk - 0.1.0)
Disk has occupied space.
```

Also the different syntax options don't change anything:

```
# raidctl -C "0.1.0 0.0.0" -r 1 1
Disk has occupied space.

# raidctl -C "0.1.0 0.0.0" 1
Disk has occupied space.
```

Ok.  Maybe this is because the disk from the spare server had a RAID 1 on it already.  Aha, I can see another volume in raidctl:

```
# raidctl -l
Controller: 1
         Volume:c1t1d0  (this is my server's root mirror)
         Volume:c1t132d0  (this is the foreign root mirror)
         Disk: 0.0.0
         Disk: 0.1.0
         ...
```

No problem.  I don't care about the data, I'll just delete the foreign mirror.

```
# raidctl -d c1t132d0
(warning about data deletion but it works)
```

At this point, /usr/bin/ binaries freak out.  By that I mean, ls -l /usr/bin/which shows 1.4k but `cat /usr/bin/which` gives me a newline.  Great, I just blew away the binaries (ie: binaries in mem still work)?  I bounce the box.  It all comes back fine.  WTF.  Anyway, back to recreating my mirror.

```
# raidctl -l
Controller: 1
         Volume:c1t1d0  (this is my server's root mirror)
         Disk: 0.0.0
         Disk: 0.1.0
         ...
```

Man says that you can delete a mirror and it will split it.  Ok, I'll delete the root mirror.

```
# raidctl -d c1t0d0
Array in use.  (this might not be the exact error)
```

I googled this and found of course you can't do this (even with -f) while booted off the mirror.  Ok.  I `boot cdrom -s` and deleted the volume.

Now I have one disk that has a type of "LSI-Logical-Volume" on c1t1d0 (where my data is) and a brand new "Hitachi 146GB" on c1t0d0 (what I'm trying to mirror to):

```
(booted off the CD)
# raidctl -c c1t1d0 c1t0d0 (man says it's source destination for mirroring)
Illegal Array Layout.

# raidctl -C "0.1.0 0.0.0" -r 1 1  (alt syntax per man)
Illegal Array Layout.

# raidctl -C "0.1.0 0.0.0" 1  (assumes raid1, no help)
Illegal Array Layout.
```

Same size disks, same manufacturer but I did delete the volume instead of throwing in a blank disk and waiting for it to resync.  Maybe this was a critical error.  I tried selecting the type in format for my good disk to be a plain 146gb disk but it resets the partition table which I'm pretty sure would wipe the data (bad if this was production).

Am I boned?  Anyone have experience with breaking and resyncing a mirror?  There's nothing on Google about "Illegal Array Layout" so here's my contrib to the search gods.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, I could not find an answer to this.  But I did find a workaround and some good information.  First off, this was on 10/08 (U6) of Solaris 10.  I booted off a 10/09 boot CD (U8) and found that there's a bug in raidctl on U8.  U8 fails with a "Corrupt labe - bad geometry" error.  Even when I wiped the disks completely I was unable to re-create a mirror using the U8 boot CD but on U7 (and presumably U6) the exact same command worked.  So just a bit of version warning there.

The gist of the workaround went something like this (substitute your disks, paths, etc).

- My partitions were split but I could see the data off the boot CD.  I needed a lot of space to do a ufsdump so I imported a large zfs pool.  This could mean different things to you, maybe just mount a large partition.  Let's call it /mnt/space.
- Copy or dump each of your existing partition table to a file.  Remember you're booted off the CD at this point.

  - format (1, p, p) or do a `prtvtoc /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s2 > /mnt/space/partitions.txt`
- Backup partitions

  - `ufsdump 0f - /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s0 > /mnt/space/root_c1t1d0s0.dmp`
  - `ufsdump 0f - /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s4 > /mnt/space/var_c1t1d0s4.dmp`
  - continue for each partition
- Recreate raid (off U7 or older CD, U8 has a bug, fails).

  - `raidctl -c c1t0d0 c1t1d0`  WARNING: This wipes both drives.
  - Creating RAID volume will destroy all data on spare space of member disks, proce
    ed (yes/no)? yes
- Label new raid disk with format.  You should not receive weird or failed labeling errors in format.
- Lookup your volume with `raidctl -l`  (assuming it's c1t1d0 in these instructions)
- Restore your partition layout.

  - cat /mnt/space/partitions.txt | fmthard -s - /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s2
- At this point I actually switched to DiskSuite but the restore steps are similar.
- newfs each of the partitions.

  - `newfs /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s0` (through s7, skip s2 obviously)
- Mount and restore each partition:

  - `mkdir /tmp/s0`
  - `mount /dev/rdsk/ctt1d0s0 /tmp/s0`
  - `cd /tmp/s0`
  - `cat /mnt/space/root_c1t1d0s0.dmp | ufsrestore xf -`  (answer yes to root dir permission)
  - `umount /tmp/s0`
  - repeat for each slice
- Copy the boot block.  The path to this file depends on your hardware:

  - `installboot platform/SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220/lib/fs/ufs/bootblk /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s0`
- Unmount everything, export zpools if need be, reboot off the CD.
- Edit your alias from the open boot prompt

  - `probe-scei-all`
  - `show-disks` (select disk)
  - `nvalias disk Ctrl-Y`
  - `boot disk`
- At this point you should be back to a hardware mirror or perhaps you switched to DiskSuite.

If you want to switch to disksuite in the middle of all this:
 - backup using ufsdump as above
 - delete your hardware raid definition
 - restore partitions to a 1st disk, newfs the partitions on the 1st disk
 - ufsrestore to the 1st disk, do a sanity boot
 - then start the regular disksuite install.
If you try to do disksuite off the CD all in one-shot, it won't take because the meta service isn't running.  You'll get this error:
`metadb: network/rpc/meta:default: failed to enable/disable SVM service`
Doing the meta commands won't hurt, they just won't stick.  IE: when you reboot off your harddisk, metastat will says "no meta databases found".