# Issue with broken disk on Solaris with raidctl - how to proceed

Tags: raid, solaris, mirroring

I have a SunFire T2000 server which has 2 mirrored disks pairs. The server required an exchange of the system battery. After swaping the battery first no disks were found. 
After booting from CD we managed to find the disks, but now one disk is broken and the raidctl reports a failed synchronisation. 
The boot process stops now when trying to mount the file systems. The power light of the broken drive is not even blinking.
What is the best way to proceed now ? Fortunately I could live with loosing the data on the drive as it is backed up, but I would like to keep the rest of the data as it contains /etc and get the server booting again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to boot from a single disk by breaking the mirror. A good info in serverfault itself [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/114368/splitting-a-raidctl-mirror-safely).

Comment: I saw this but the comment of my admin was that it was too complex - but it looked very reasonable.

Comment: Its definitely not too complex and this is non-destructive method.
Which is why it is call "mirroring", so that at any point you can boot at least a single disk and replace all the spoil disk and rebuild the mirror.

Comment: It was more scarier for me when I have to break the mirror for an older sunfire box, with Sol 8. With T2000, you definitely are using Sol 10.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if mirroring was set "properly", you can even boot to one of the disk by simply using the boot alias at the "ok" prompt.